# Google drive indicates my self-made apk as a virus?

Tags: android, security, apk, google-play-protect

When I try to install a self-made APK from google Drive, I get the message: "apk is infected with a virus".

[image]

or something like this:

[image]

I uploaded the APK to https://www.virustotal.com and only the google check failed. But I get no further indication why.

I use the following dependencies in my build.gradle(module-level)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    ...
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 33
    }
}

dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.5.0"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.2.0"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.2.0"

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-paging:$room_version")

    androidTestImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version")
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.5.0'

    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")

    testImplementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.44")
    kaptTest("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")

    androidTestImplementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.44")
    kaptAndroidTest("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
}
```

and build.gradle(top-level)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.6.0-alpha07")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version "2.45" apply false
}
```

On my Android device I use Android 13.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix the problem or get more information about which file or library is causing this error?

Comment: Where did you get this message? on Google Drive or on an Android device? Did you try installing it on a different Android device? What's the Android version? Put a screenshot of the actual error message.

Comment: I get the virus warning when I try to download the apk on my desktop PC. When I try to download on the Android device, I just get a connection error message. Unfortunately I don't have another Android device and only used an emulator to test it. My Android device uses Android 13

Comment: Got any fix for this?
i am facing the same issue when i share a apk through drive..
and im not sure how to fix this ,it would be great help if you have the answer

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala
i'm getting when i try to download the apk in android devices from drive link,
android version - all the devices i had is showing the error - 11,12,13,
do you have any solution for this? it would be a great help if you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the `debuggable true` option in release buildTypes in build.gradle(module-level) is responsible for the warning message.
I was not aware that this option would cause google Drive to block the apk and believe that the option had been enabled for some time. However, the APK can now be installed as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by updating the Constraint Layout version in the apps build.gradle from 2.1.4 to 2.2.0:

`androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.2.0-alpha13`